# Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x110a22770) to 'NSString'

Tags: swift

```
func addUserObserver(_ update: @escaping () -> Void) {
    FriendSystem.system.USER_REF.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        self.userList.removeAll()
        for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            let email = child.childSnapshot(forPath: "email").value as! String
            if email != Auth.auth().currentUser?.email! {
                self.userList.append(User(userEmail: email, userID: child.key))
            }
        }
        update()
    })

}
```

I am getting a signal sigabbt error in the following line let email = child.childSnapshot(forPath: "email").value as! String any tips as to what may cause this given that I am using firebase as a backend.

Comment: `child.childSnapshot(forPath: "email").value` is returning an NSNull and you are force unwrapping it to a String.  I don't know much about firebase but that suggests that the email is null in the database.

Comment: Please [search on the error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=could+not+cast+nsnull+to+nsstring+%5Bswift%5D) before posting.